# vis.js node placement when physics is disabled

Tags: vis.js

How can you disable physics in vis.js with a large number of nodes and no edges without having all the nodes appear in a circle? Pastebin is disabled for work, so I won't post everything, but here are my options:

```
var options = {
    physics: { enabled: false },
    layout: { improvedLayout: false }
    }
```

For some reason all the nodes appear in a circle. When I reenable physics, they are correctly spaced out. I would appreciate any help anyone could give me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm the developer of the network module of vis.js. What you're seeing is the default starting position. The improved layout is a solution to this which you also disable.. What exactly are you expecting to get out of this? The physics position the nodes. Without it they are randomly positioned.

You can manually provide x and y values to nodes, you can try hierarchical or if you want to turn physics off AFTER they are positioned, use the stabilizationIterationsDone event.

These events are shown in our examples and documentation.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks so much! Worked like a charm!

Comment: Hi Alex! After enabling physics, while moving nodes around, it has become laggy. Although with physics enabled it works correctly. Any suggestions?